# .NET WebClient.DownloadFile *not* throwing on a 404

Tags: c#, .net, webclient

I have a WebClient.DownloadFile call which for some reason isn't throwing when (the site is valid/responsive but) the file doesn't exist.
I've pasted the same code block elsewhere - into the top of a unit test, as it happens, and there it *does* throw a 404 as expected.

```
                    try
                    {
                        using (var client = new System.Net.WebClient())
                        {
                            client.DownloadFile("http://example.com/NoSuchFile", "savedFile");
                        }
                    }

                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Download failed");
                    }
```

Any thoughts anyone please? I don't know if it's relevant, but the non-working invocation is in the callback of a System.Timers.Timer; .NET Framework 4.6.1

Comment: Why are you using `WebClient` **at all** in 2022?

Comment: You're swallowing exceptions with that empty `catch` block, what makes you think it isn't being used?

Comment: Sorry - my bad quoting: for simplicity I removed my custom debug message....   A breakpoint on it doesn't get hit, nor does the code that I actually have in there. Something real added now - sorry for the bum steer.
What I do get is an empty file.

Comment: If you get an empty file, then the most likely cause is that the site served you up an empty response. There is no (hard) requirement that you get a 404. If you need more details you'll have to either hook up a web trace of some sort (Fiddler, Wireshark) or move away from the `DownloadFile` convenience method and pull apart the response with more detail.

Comment: `WebClient` only throws exception on network errors. You should check the `status` of the response, iy will show `404`.

Comment: Hmmm, yes, and maybe no. I tried the 'same' request with curl and that did give a 404. AND that code does throw when I drop it into a unit test - just somewhere convenient to try it 'on it's own' as opposed to in my actual code-under-test. 

Maybe I do need to look at a Wireshark of it to rule out server-side stuff.

Comment: Why I'm using WebClient lol?  - just that it seemed simple and straight-forward to use for my purposes.... I'd hoped....!!  :S   - a few downloads a day max